# Linux batch: create multi folder by combine name with serial number

Tags: linux, shell

I'm try to create multi folder by combine string and counter. I don't why what is the wrong with my code:

```
  echo 'Start'
  let count=0
  for p in {1..10}
  do

      DirName= "dir"
      NUM = "${DirName}${count}"
      let count++
      mkdir $NUM
      mkdir "$NUM"/decoded

  done
```

I got this kind of error

```
  ./test.sh: line 6: dir: command not found
  ./test.sh: line 7: NUM: command not found
```

thank in advance

Comment: Are you trying to create "multiple folders" or is "muti folder" something specific?

Comment: Shell scripts may be picky about white space. Remove the spaces before and after the equal signs.

Comment: Use a shebang for your script so that we know what shell are you using and be specific about it in your tags.

Comment: @Yeti I attempt to create multi-folders. I am sorry to confuse you.

Comment: @BjornA. I just deleted the space then it works -:  thank you

Answer (score 3):

No need to use a loop here. The shell will do all the necessary expansion for you. In fact, you're already relying on the shell to expand `{1..10}` for you as part of your `for` loop. So you can just use that expansion directly with `mkdir`. Also by using `mkdir -p <path>` (make parent directories as needed), you can avoid having to first do `mkdir $NUM` before doing `mkdir $NUM/decoded`.

Putting it all together, you can do what you need in a single line:

```
mkdir -p dir{1..10}/decoded
```

**Edit**: To answer your question more directly regarding the `command not found` errors, it looks like (as Bjorn A. mentioned) you just need to get rid of the spaces before and after the `=` in your variable assignments.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have spaces around the assignment operator in bash. Lines 6 and 7 must look like:

```
DirName="dir"
NUM="${DirName}${count}"
```